# Strange thing while burning an ISO file with Ubuntu Studio to usb using dd

Tags: usb, iso, dd, ubuntu-studio, burning

I burned an ISO file with Ubuntu Studio and I did it using status=progress. When I started the process of burning I saw that there was already 1 GB (when you use status=progress it shows how much GB was already burned to usb through the process). It was kind of strange for me, because now I think that something went wrong.
I just installed the OS using this bootable usb and everything seems to work right, and after the process of burning I checked the size of partition on bootable usb and it was 3.6G. My iso file was 3.8GB, but I think that 3.6 is in GiB, so it's all must be correct.
Can you tell me if it's fine that the status=process showed the process like this? Is it normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is due to the fact that Ubuntu uses all its free memory for disk caching. The utility `dd` "thinks" it has written the USB while in reality, its output goes to the memory cache, from where it is committed to disk. This goes fast at first, as the memory is being filled. SO that is where you see it going very fast.

Then further progress is with the real speed: at the same speed the cache is being written, memory becomes available to `dd` to continue its operation. Once it has finished, the prompt reappears. However, writing to the USB still continues in the background.

If you want to really see when the USB is fully written, append a `sync` command to your  `dd` command, as in

```
dd if=... of= ... ; sync
```

Sync tells the system to flush the cache. This way, your terminal prompt will appear again only when writing really is finished, and you will be sure the physical writing to the USB actually is completed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, really! I also wanted to mention, that I was creating Bootable USB in Manjaro, not Ubuntu, as you mentioned. But I think it will apply to pretty much any distro out there. Also I wanted to say that the process started straight from the 1 GB, not from 0. Is it play any role in it? But maybe it was that fast that I just didn't notice. So, I don't have to worry, right? Thanks for mentioning the sync command!